# Sails-React : Receive data on programmatic redirection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js

I'm developing a web application using Sails and React. In this, I'm registering the user and redirecting them to home page passing id as a param. So after redirection, `UserController's` home action is getting called.

**Here is the code 'api/controller/UserController'**

```
home : function(req,res){
        var userId = parseInt(req.params.id);

        sails.log.warn('Home req.params.id :: ',userId);

        if(userId && typeof userId === "number"){
            User.findOne(userId)
                .then(function(user){

                    sails.log.info('Sending user [home]:: ',user);
                    Router.run(routes, '/user/home/' + userId, function(Root){

                       return res.view("homepage",{
                        'body'  : React.renderToString(<Root/>),
                        'user'  : user
                       });
                    });
                }).catch(function(err){
                    sails.log.error('Error while finding user :: ',err);
                    return res.negotiate(err);
                })
        }else{
            return res.badRequest("User id must be a Integer value","400");
        }

    }
```

What should I do, to display user information using my React component?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action which handles the form submission, you should store the user's ID in your session, e.g.:

```
req.session.me = newlyCreatedUser.id;
// Session is saved automatically when request is sent.
return res.redirect('/');
```

This means that your new user is also effectively "logged in".

Then in your `home` controller action, instead of grabbing the user's id from the parameter, grab it from the session.

For a more thorough walkthrough, see [sails101/basic-login](https://github.com/sails101/basic-login/blob/master/api/controllers/UserController.js#L65).  Good luck!

> Side note: As a rule of thumb, I would suggest using an AJAX request + loading spinner + client-side redirect (`window.location='/'`) to submit your forms *instead of* a traditional HTML form submission + backend `res.redirect()` where possible.  It tends to keep things cleaner for your app down the road, and helps encourage your backend to organically develop in a future-friendly way.  Plus I just tend to think it's easier to reason about.